# In xamarin forms can use sql query

Tags: sql, .net, c#-4.0, xamarin.forms

I need to retrieve data from my local database.in xamarin forms it uses linq.can i use SQL query instead of linq

Answer (score 1):

There is [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases) that answers your question:

> Xamarin.Forms applications can use the SQLite.NET PCL NuGet package to
>   incorporate database operations into shared code by referencing the
>   SQLite classes that ship in the NuGet. Database operations can be
>   defined in the .NET Standard library project of the Xamarin.Forms
>   solution.

and example from the same [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases):

```
public Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsNotDoneAsync()
{
  return database.QueryAsync<TodoItem>("SELECT * FROM [TodoItem] WHERE [Done] = 0");
}
```